# how to manipulate array in array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have got a `X_train` np.array with shape of `(1433, 1)`. The first dimension (`1433`) is the number of images for training. The second dimension (`1`) is an np.array which itself has a shape `(224, 224, 3)`. I could confirm it by `X_train[0][0].shape`. I need to fit `X_train` to the model:

```
model.fit([X_train, y_train[:,1:]], y_train[:,0], epochs=50, batch_size=32,  verbose=1)
```

Error output is self-explanatory:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/combined/file_01.py", line 97, in <module>
    img_output = Flatten()(x_1)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 414, in __call__
    self.assert_input_compatibility(inputs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 327, in assert_input_compatibility
    str(K.ndim(x)))
ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer flatten_1: expected min_ndim=3, found ndim=2
```

`y_train[:,1:]` seems to be OK with a shape `(1433, 9)`.

What do I need to do with `X_train` in `model.fit` to successfully be able to input as (1433, 224, 224, 3)?

Comment: Can you show how you create the model? Or model summary

Comment: @Sreeram TP I was able to resolve the issue, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you have a case like this:

```py
import numpy as np
x_train = np.zeros((1433, 1), dtype=object)
for i in range(x_train.shape[0]):
    x_train[i, 0] = np.random.random((224, 224, 3))

x_train.shape        # (1433, 1)
x_train[0, 0].shape  # (224, 224, 3)
```

Where `x_train` is an `object` array (like a nested list) not an `numeric` array.

You need to change `x_train` to a pure `numeric` array:

```
x_train = np.array([x for x in x_train.flatten()], dtype=float)
x_train.shape       # (1433, 224, 224, 3)
x_train[0].shape    # (224, 224, 3)
```

Comment: thanks for the help, it did help to match the dimensions but the same error continues to happen.

Comment: hi again, I resolved the issue after some look ups, it was due to my mistake (flattening the already flattened output) and guess your answer played a significant role. I'll accept your answer.